# Correct way to pass data from one view to another in django?

Tags: python, django, fitbit

Currently Im trying to build an app using Django that pull data from fitbit. Im in the process of getting the Oauth2.0 connection to work.

So I generated a authorization url from a bunch of user inputs: fitbit url, fitbit api, fitbit client id, fitbit client secret and redirect url. Once the link is generated and visited, fitbit returns with an access code in the URL like: https://localhost:8000/?code=#*=*

Im able to extract the access code, but Im not sure what is the correct way to obtain the previous user input data in the newly redirected view. One way I can think of is saving the first user inputs into a DB and then pulling it out when redirected with the new access code. But Im not sure what other options are available and what the standard way of doing this is.

Im still new to django, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you should start by posting what you'have tested

Comment: sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: I see two possibilities: Passing data through GET parameters, which has many disadvantages, mainly related related with security since the user may manipulate it as he wants, the other approach is using messages framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) or django-flash(http://danielfm.me/django-flash/usage.html)

Comment: hmm i think maybe saving to a database and then pulling the information again might be the safest way

Answer (score 0):

you can pass in URL query params if data is not sensitive otherwise you can use session value.

Comment: would that work even if the user gets redirected away from the app to a fitbit authorization page and back to the app?

Comment: a session will keep value until you don't pop